# Python: Can't assign to operator

Tags: python, math, operator-keyword, assign

Writing a battle sequence for a game, and this error is showing on the bottom line where the actual arithmetic should be occurring and being applied in the background. I'm assuming it's an error related to method of the arithmetic?

```
if choice == 'A':
        print(curChar[NAME] + "attacks!")
        attackHit = True
        if WEAPON_ACCURACY < 100:
            if roll() > WEAPON_ACCURACY:
                attackHit = False
                print(curChar[NAME], "'s attack missed!")

        else:
            attackHit == True
            print(curChar[NAME], "'s attack landed and dealt", curChar[STRENGTH] + curChar[WEAPON_DAMAGE] - curEnemy[HEALTH] + curEnemy[ARMOR], "damage!")
            **curChar[HEALTH] + curChar[ARMOR] - curEnemy[STRENGTH] - curEnemy[WEAPON_DAMAGE] = curChar[HEALTH]**
```

Comment: What does it mean to assign to an addition? This is basic syntax, common to most programming languages, that you can only assign to variables, not calculations (an exception is Prolog, which is able to invert calculations by treating them as logical equivalences).

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of the order in which you assign variables. The target is on the left, the computation is on the right.

`curChar[HEALTH] = curChar[HEALTH] + curChar[ARMOR] - curEnemy[STRENGTH] - curEnemy[WEAPON_DAMAGE]`

Comment: Unrelated, but this line is wrong, too: "attackHit == True", you just want one equals sign there.  However, your code would be work the same if your removed EITHER of the "attackHit = True" lines.

Comment: As an aside, if armor is high, then being hit might *add* to the player's health! Instead, try `curChar[HEALTH] -= max(0, curEnemy[STRENGTH] + curEnemy[WEAPON_DAMAGE] - curChar[ARMOR]`